# How Pass parameters and access them in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="">
<script>
 for(i=0;i<50;i++)
 {
  document.writeln("<input type='button' value ='"+i+"'        onclick='clicked(i)'/>");

 }
function clicked(Number x)
{
 alert("selected:" +x);
}
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to know which button is selected in this code how to perform that please can someone help me

Comment: `function clicked(Number x)` - javascript 101 - this is not how you define a function, and check the **developer** tools console for errors

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just do the same in this method:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  document.writeln("<input type='button' value='" + i + "' onclick='alert(this.value)'>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out how to declare functions in JavaScript here:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to know its value.</p>

<button value="1" onclick="myFunction(this.value)">A</button>
<button value="2" onclick="myFunction(this.value)">B</button>
<button value="3" onclick="myFunction(this.value)">C</button>

<script>
function myFunction(value) {
 alert(value);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```